# If the Berserkers don't lose their memories when they return as a ghost, why does someone lose them?

Tags: artemis-fowl, artemis-fowl-the-last-guardian

In *Artemis Fowl: the Last Guardian*,

> Artemis dies,

and is cloned back to life, and his spirit remains, but he has not retained his memories.

Why? Is it just because humans are not as "magical" as the Berserkers?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question